# How to implement ktor's client in typesafe

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I am a kotlin newbie and am getting introduced to ktor by looking at the following page.
https://ktor.io/docs/type-safe-request.html#resource_url

So I want to make a type safe request and I have written the following code.

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.resources.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.resources.Resources

@Resource("/")
class Hoge()

class Client {

    private val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(Resources)
        defaultRequest {
            host = "10.0.2.2"
            port = 8000
            url {
                protocol = URLProtocol.HTTP
            }
        }
    }

    public fun hoge(): String {
        val res = client.get(Hoge())
        return res.bodyAsText()
    }
}
```

So I received the following error.

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public suspend inline fun HttpClient.get(builder: HttpRequestBuilder): HttpResponse defined in io.ktor.client.request
public suspend inline fun HttpClient.get(block: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit): HttpResponse defined in io.ktor.client.request
public suspend inline fun HttpClient.get(url: Url, block: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit = ...): HttpResponse defined in io.ktor.client.request
public suspend fun HttpClient.get(url: URL, block: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit = ...): HttpResponse defined in io.ktor.client.request
public suspend inline fun HttpClient.get(urlString: String, block: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit = ...): HttpResponse defined in io.ktor.client.request
```

I implemented it as per the official page, but I am getting the error and I don't know how to solve it. I am looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import this extension function:

```
io.ktor.client.plugins.resources.get
```

You also need to be calling `client.get()` inside of a [suspending function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html). Either make `hoge()` a suspend fun or introduce some coroutine context. Here is a version of your code that compiles for me. I've commented the fixes and modified it slightly to follow kotlin convention.

```kt
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.*
// this import is what imports the extension functions you need
import io.ktor.client.plugins.resources.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.resources.Resources
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.resources.*

@Resource("/")
class Hoge

class Client {
    private val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(Resources)
        defaultRequest {
            host = "10.0.2.2"
            port = 8000
            url {
                protocol = URLProtocol.HTTP
            }
        }
    }

    // you need to use a suspend function to call ktor client methods
    suspend fun hoge(): String {
        val res = client.get(Hoge())
        return res.bodyAsText()
    }
}
```